# command blkid don't show my partitions UUID

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu, blkid

I'm using Ubuntu. command `blkid` or `blk /dev/sda2` in LPIC-1 module 104.3 (mounting and unmounting). but these commands don't show me the expected results. **blkid** is installed and also I can see `man blkid` !!!

Could you guide me to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `sudo blkid`

After that you will be able to get the same result with simply running `blkid` (without sudo)

Comment: OMG! just needed root access! but why didn't tel me **root access Error** ??

Comment: because it doesn't need root access always...For ex. If you had any usb drive mounted as normal user you could see it with just running `blkid` without sudo.